# .NET Core command line interface fails to launch app on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, .net-core

I have used the following instructions to install .NET Core command line interface on my ubuntu box: https://github.com/dotnet/cli

the `dotnet restore` and `dotnet compile` work just fine. However I am getting the following error when trying to run the app with `dotnet run`:

failed to locate CLR files at /usr/share/dotnet/runtime/coreclr

Note that I have set the DOTNET_HOME to /usr/share/dotnet (as required by the instructions), however no runtime seems to be found at that location

Comment: Have you been able to resolve the issue? The dotnet Utility chain were pretty early builds at time of questioning. Now the are in RC2 and avavilable as apt-get.

Comment: @Thomas I gave up because the level of support for .net core is not what I would expect from a production quality platform. In other words I am waiting until the dust settles and MS gives us tools that actually work :)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "Production" ready as of yet but I have had a lot of success putting together a few apps running Ubuntu 16.04.  EntityFramework is working alot better as well.  I am building an app currently running on Linux with PostgreSql and the setup was very easy.